# how to add images folder in ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

how to add the 'images' folder that appears by default in CK Editor when you try and upload an image.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First extract the downloaded file into the CKEditor’s plugins folder. Then enable the plugin by changing or adding the extraPlugins line in your configuration (config.js):

Defining Configuration In-Page

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'
});
```

Using the config.js File

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader';
};
```

Don't forget to set **CHMOD writable permission (0777)** to the imageuploader folder on your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'
});
```